# Django Created By and Modified By in an Abstract Base Class

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, abstract-class

I want to create an Abstract Base Class that other models inherit to track some basic information (Created_Date, Mod_date, Created_by, Mod_by, etc) here is an example of what I would like:

```
class MetaDataModel(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

However, when I use this class in more than one other model I receive an error telling me:

> takeoffs.Takeoff.added_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'Takeoff.added_by' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'InputTakeoffItem.added_by'.
>
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Takeoff.added_by' or 'InputTakeoffItem.added_by'.

across all models it's implemented in.

How can I create a ABC to track both who created and last modified an Item?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry after struggling with this for a couple days, I actually found the answer in Django's documentation. There are two variables(?) you can add to the related_name field:

- %(app_label)s
- %(class)s

This will make the related_name unique to each class inheriting from it.

Documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name